# How to use same object across packages

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have 2 packages, 1st the Base package `package ceccms.automation.framework` and another package `package ceccms.testcases` as follows:
    package ceccms.automation.framework;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class UniversalMethods {

public static WebDriver driver = null;
public static String chromepath = "D:\\Automation\\Web Drivers\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe";
public static String edgepath = "D:\\Automation\\Web Drivers\\EdgeDriver\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";

public WebDriver openBrowser (String browser, String url) {

    if (browser != null) {
        switch (browser) {
        case "Mozilla":
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get(url);
            break;
        case "Chrome":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromepath);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get(url);
            break;
        case "Edge":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", edgepath);
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
            driver.get(url);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Browser Name");
            driver.quit();

        }
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return driver;
}

}
```

and

```
package ceccms.testcases;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import ceccms.automation.framework.UniversalMethods;

public class LoginTest {

public static String url = "https://test.ceccms.com/Login.aspx?";

static UniversalMethods U = new UniversalMethods();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    String browserName = "Chrome";
    U.openBrowser(browserName, url);

    WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName"));
    userName.sendKeys("pkumar");
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserPass"));
    password.sendKeys("PassMe33");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.quit();

}

}
```

I am running the code through the second package. I want to use one object `driver` across the package without using the notation `U.driver.findElement()` . How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions, you can add Page Objects, where define Web elements and give your Driver as parameter to initiate Page object class with all web elements. This will allow you to work directly with elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it, with this structure(By extending universal method):

```
package ceccms.testcases;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import ceccms.automation.framework.UniversalMethods;

public class LoginTest extends UniversalMethods {

    //You can access driver and method without using object reference 

    public static String url = "https://test.ceccms.com/Login.aspx?";   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    String browserName = "Chrome";
    openBrowser(browserName, url);

    WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName"));
    userName.sendKeys("pkumar");
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserPass"));
    password.sendKeys("PassMe33");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Inheritence was in my mind but `UniversalMethods` will serve as a class with N number of methods so inheriting it, will it not increase the execution time? `LoginTest` is a Testcase and I will be writing a number of such testcases and may be running them simultaneously using Saucelabs. In that case will it be a problem ?

Anyother suggestions ?

Thanks...

Comment: Not a single problem. Code don't realize even. I am even using same approach.

Comment: Thanks @Ishita, It worked like a charm. I integrated TestNG also, so now its even more feasible to manage.

Comment: @PratikKumar Please accept my answer and upvote (when its enable for you) it.